# Can I extend the range of this 433.92 MHz gate opener by soldering a copper wire to it as antenna?

Tags: rf, antenna, 433mhz

I have a 433.92 MHz gate opener remote that I would like to be able to control from my phone. In order to do this I have soldered a relay to one of its buttons, which I already have means to trigger through Home Assistant.

Sadly, the range isn't good enough to reliably reach the receiver. I have thought about somehow adding an extra antenna to it to increase the distance it can transmit.

I suspect that the area I marked with purple on this image is the current antenna: [image: HR TECH3 Remote circuit board]

Is my assumption correct, and is it worth trying to extend the range by soldering some extra copper wire to it? In case it's worth a try, is my research so far correct, that suggests that I should be using a copper wire of length ~173mm?

---

*Edit #1:* I have identified the remote as being an HR TECH3: https://www.hrmatic.es/producto/hr-tech3-remote-control/

---

*Edit #2:* I finally went with the [idea of @Chu](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/626879/206656) and built a passive reflector. So far it seems to work very well! I wish I could accept it as correct too, but I guess that strictly speaking [@Marcus Müller's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/626879/206656) addresses the original question more directly.

[image: passive reflector]

Comment: If you do this, technically you'll run afoul of FCC regulations.   Highly unlikely you'll get caught, but you ought at least be aware.....

Comment: The reason why these don't have very good range is because they are using cheap designs. "433.92" is already a warning sign right there, because it usually means it's intended to wideband spam down the whole band +/- some 500kHz, possibly also some naive modulation like OOK. Neither is feasible on these public bands. If there's a construction site nearby with lots of remote controlled machinery, then these cheap radios tend to be jammed out, as per their own cheap, bad design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

You can build a *better antenna*, which would mostly mean that in exchance for needing to point more exactly, you can get a bit more gain in one direction.

But making a better antenna is harder than just adding some copper, which will destroy the matching / tuning of the antenna and almost certainly make it worse.

Notice that the tree-contacts device on the right hand side is probably a transistor used as a power amplifier for the RF signal, and so its performance is directly coupled to the antenna having the right, probably reactive, impedance. So, actually making this a transmitter with more gain will be more or less a redesign of the RF stage. No way that pays.

Atop of that, changes are it's illegal to increase the gain, as PAPR is limited for ISM devices in most countries.

A better bet would be to replace the antenna of the receiver, which probably is less directly coupled into an amplifier other than being connected via a matched-impedance line, and seeing this does not seem to be a two-way communication link, is not going to break any laws. Or, just replace the whole receiver with an SDR + raspberry pi + relay card, or something.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and thorough reply!
I don't feel like messing around with making the RF beam more directed / concentrated and having to aim more precisely, so I guess that I'll have to look for another device with higher output right out of the box. (I'm sure that some exist, as my mother-in-law's gate opener works from much farther away than mine.) The Raspberry Pi route also seems viable! :)

Comment: higher output isn't what you're looking for; you just want a device with better reach. The fact that you're not coming far with what you currently have is not because the transmitter has too little output power - it's that the receiver isn't sensitive enough, and that's probably the case because the system was designed so simple that it simply can't be more sensitive without misinterpreting a lot of noise as signal.

Comment: i.e. your current system is probably pretty bad in terms of reach per watt, and limited in the amount of watt it can transmit. A different system might be subject to the same power limit, but simply be a better system and get further with the same amount of power.

Comment: Does the system have to be wireless all the way? Can you move the remote control closer to the gate? Or perhaps higher up or some other location with a better line of sight?

Comment: @DDuck I've also been thinking about that, like having some extra wiring between the relay and the remote (I'd guess that a pair of an ethernet cable should be fine for this purpose), but in order to get it closer I'd have to somehow make it go outside of the house, and I don't want to drill a hole into the wall / window.  Thanks for the suggestion though! 

Answer (score 2):

Form a quad antenna by adding passive reflector and/or director elements on the outside of the case. The physical dimensions of the case/PCB would need to be capable of providing appropriate separation between passive and driven elements.

Comment: Wow, this seems like an interesting idea that I could try without way too much effort! I'll read up on quad antennas, as I'm not yet familiar with those. Could 3D printing a parabolic shape and wrapping it into tinfoil also work for such a purpose?

Comment: You could build a "corner-reflector Yagi" for 433 MHz and mount your transmitter at the driven element.  BTW 433MHz is not that far from the 470MHz of TV channel 14 (in the United States) so you might experiment with an old or discarded UHF TV antenna.